# Place div with overlapping images at the bottom

Tags: html, css

**Edited for clarity:**

I have some images which should overlap each other and be placed at the bottom of the fixed div, #all.

The image's top and left values should dictate their position relative to their container. This allows them to overlap each other.

That container should be placed at the bottom of #all.

The problem is that the image_container div isn't going to the bottom.

HTML:

```
<div id="all">
  <div id="left">
    <div>Some Text</div>
    <div id=image_container>
      <img style="left: 50px; top: 50px" src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/thumb_large/1148591/116239540/stock-vector-orange-icon-116239540.jpg">
      <img style="left: 20px; top: 100px" src="https://thumb10.shutterstock.com/thumb_large/713587/111988943/stock-vector-icon-orange-111988943.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#all{
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
}
#left{
  float: left;
}
#left > div{
  display: block;
}
#image_container{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
}
#image_container > img{
  position: absolute;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Le9rats3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#all {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh; /* for demo purposes */
}
#left {
  height: 100%;
}

#image_container {
  position: relative;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#image_container img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
}

#image_container img:nth-child(2) {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <div id="left">
    <div>Some Text</div>
    <div id=image_container>
      <img style="" src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/thumb_large/1148591/116239540/stock-vector-orange-icon-116239540.jpg">
      <img style="" src="https://thumb10.shutterstock.com/thumb_large/713587/111988943/stock-vector-icon-orange-111988943.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I'm really confused by your mark up. But if you're asking to explicitly make up the height of image_container span the height of the images, then you need to set the height of #left to 100%, and the height of image_container to 100%.

Update: I updated my fiddle according to your updated answer. #image_container needs to be relative, and the images need to be absolute to it. **Run it on fullscreen to see how the images are pushed to bottom of the image container.**

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `position: relative`. If you want to position relative to the page, use `position: absolute`. If you want to position relative to te viewport use `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear what you want here, but ill take a shot at it.
https://jsfiddle.net/Le9rats3/3/

Your problem is that `position:relative` only works in another element that is positioned as either: `fixed`, `absolute`, or `relative`.

Further, `position: relative` positions it relative to where it would "naturally" line up. In this case, you would want to use `absolute`.

See fiddle for code.

Comment: I have edited the question to improve clarity. This solution works in terms of placing the container at the bottom of the page, but the images are no longer placed according to their top and left values. They should be placed relative to their container based on those values. Essentially, the left and top values should be the offset from the parent container.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you mean via something already built online or simply through making a quick image in Google Draw or something?

Answer (score 0):

Elements are positioned to their parent container, but you can't position `#image_container` because it's parent, `#left`, doesn't have any height or width set nor does it have it's own `position` set, so it doesn't know where to go.